# Printing Out Corresponding Values for an Associative Array Match

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I have an associative array that have keys of 'alert' and 'email'. I've got some e-mails and I want it to run through the associative array and if the e-mail address matches the value of the 'email' key, I want to print the corresponding 'alert' value.

The array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => alert [email] => Test ) [1] => Array ( [alert] => alert [email] => Test ) )
```

And the code I have so far is this:

```
$email = "test@test.com"

foreach($alert_array as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
        if($key2=="email"){
            if($value2==$email){
                echo [THE CORRESPONDING 'ALERT'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also only want to echo out the alert value only one time and I know the way I currently have it, it will echo it out a bunch of times.

Am I using the correct loop for this? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Why the downvote? An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code can be optimized using only One foreach and a `break` is necessary if you want to `alert` only one time:

```
foreach($alert_array as $key => $value){

   if (array_key_exists('email', $value)) {
        if($value['email']==$email){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something here')</script>";
            break;
        }
    }

}
```